# Javascript - Page Reload Not working With Hashed Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently in a URL like this-

> http://localhost:8000/settings#social_accounts

I want to reload this page with [JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) / [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) so that I can have my exact URL with hash .

So what I have done is-

Way 1-

```
location.reload();
```

Way 2-

```
location.reload(true);
```

Way 3-

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

Way 4-

```
window.location.href += window.location.hash;
location.reload(window.location.href);
```

But nothing is working. Every of this 4 way is giving me a redirect to

> http://localhost:8000/settings

But I want redirect URL - http://localhost:8000/settings#social_accounts

Can anyone please help?

Comment: use window.location.href, so window.location.href = window.location.href

Comment: This is an odd behavior as `location.reload()` works fine **if the browser requested the URL with has in first, and not the URL being modified with history API

Comment: Do you have div with #social_accounts id?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this-

```js
window.location.replace( window.location.href + '#' + window.location.hash.substr(1) );
```